# Which HTML5 tags allow `disabled` attribute?

Tags: html, attributes

I just started learning HTML5 some hours ago from [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com). I came across `disabled` attribute. I want to know that what elements can be disabled using this attribute. Can I disable an `img`, `header` or paragraph tag with this attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there are some elements which can have a "disabled" attribute

- **button** elements that are disabled
- **input** elements that are disabled
- **select** elements that are disabled
- **textarea** elements that are disabled
- **optgroup** elements that have a disabled attribute
- **option** elements that are disabled
- **fieldset** elements that have a disabled attribute

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html

So according to your question, none of your given (header, img, paragraph) tags can be disabled.